# Touchpad and trackpoint not working on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: debian, touchpad

I have a ThinkPad W510 since a few month i have installed Debian 9 on it.
At the beggining both touchpad and trackpoint worked fine. Sometimes not, but a reboot fixed the problem.

Since a few days, it stoped working. I use an external mouse that work fine.

I think those lines may give you some useful information (although i dont understand what they really means)

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep usb | grep error
[    2.163011] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.351003] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.618991] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.806974] usb 3-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.414937] usb 3-1.3: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[    3.910900] usb 3-1.3: device not accepting address 6, error -32

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Web Camera                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dumb, but are you sure you didn't deactivate it by Fn+F8?

According to [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xinput/+bug/1683037) adding

`Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "libinput"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection`

into `"/etc/X11/xorg.conf"` could also help.

Comment: Fn+F8 did nothing. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` didn't exist (is it worrying ?) I created it with the section you told me and (after reboot) nothing have change.